# Notifications like facebook - What's in the URL field?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, notifications

I am implementing a facebook like notifications system in my application.
My notifications table contains following fields

```
source_id (User_id)
Type (ENUM - type of notification, eg: like,comment,new post, etc)
description (some description)
URL (the destination URL)
created_on
```

How I would work with the notifications is decided. But what I am thinking is, 
What exactly the URL column here would contain? If I put an absolute URL for a post like

```
http://facebook.com/thomas/posts/123456
```

Wouldn't this be a problem? What if the user changes its username from **thomas** to something else tomorrow?
Just needed help in how can I work with destination URL, either on frontend (I'm using PHP) or backend (in database column itself)

Answer (score 0):

Even if user will change his name (you may not allow it, by the way :-) ), his ID will likely stay the same.

So, for every type of notification, find an attribute that uniquely identifies the object and is immutable (in most cases, it's the id) and use it to build urls.

Comment: yeah am doing exactly the same. I will use object_id as a field to store that UNIQUE object id, be it post or comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine facebook uses .htaccess to pass these variables to a PHP file. So it is actually calling get.php?user=thomas&post_id=123456. So you would not have a url field, but instead associate the post with a user_id and post_id. The username "thomas" can be looked up in the user table to get the user_id, so even if the user changes their name they would keep the same unique user_id. So if you wanted to display a url you would generate the url from this data.

Comment: thnx for the reply. just a moment before I decided to use object_id, and object_type. Object_id would be any id, eg: post_id,comment_id,etc, and object_type would allow me to format the URL at the server side. thnx mate :)